# How is Jenkins helpful to automate deployment process

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, jenkins

Can anyone provide insights of using Jenkins for automating deployment under controlled and uncontrolled enviroments. We have different environments - dev/qa/uat/prod and currently we are using batch files that call msbuild/nant scripts to deploy on web and DB servers (web farm). Developers only have access to dev/qa and production support will deploy on uat/prod. Prod. support will get the source code from SVN tag folder and run the batch file to deploy the application.

By using Jenkins, is it possible to eliminate the step of prod. support team getting the script from SVN by running the jobs using their credentials via url. And what is the general practice using source control and CI tool for deploying applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to reserve Jenkins for just building the software. That way the user of Jenkins only have access to development and perhaps QA systems.

To decouple the build system from the process that deploys the software I recommend the use of a binary repository manager like:

- [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/)
- [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview)
- [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/index.cgi)

In that way deployment scripts could retrieve any version of a previous build. The use of a repository manager would enable your QA team to certify a release prior to it's deployment onto production.

Finally, consider one of the emerging deployment automation tools. Tools like [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/), [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/), [Rundeck](http://rundeck.org/) can be used to further version control the configuration of your infrastructure.

[image]